# Firebase functions: onChange for subcollections

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im making a type of chat app. The structure is something like this: there is a special type of user, a stingray, represented by a document. Each stingray can hold a collection of messages,'messages', which holds different chat data models with unique id's. It looks like this:

[image]

Im trying to implement a cloud function that listens to the stingray collection, and when a message document is updated, send a push notification to the relevant user. Is this possible? Im confused on how to implement it, because there can be multiple stingrays, each with their own 'messages' collection.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a Cloud Function that triggers on all `stingrays` subcollections with:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('/stingrays/{docId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

Also see the documentation on [Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

If the `stingrays` are subcollections of (for example) documents in a collection called `toplevel`, you can trigger on all of them with:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('/toplevel/{toplevelId}/stingrays/{docId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

In both cases, you can get the value of the parameters in the path with `context.params.docId` and (in the latter case) `context.params.toplevelId`.

Comment: You're sure this works? Looking through the documentation, they mention in this part:

'If a document in users has subcollections, and a field in one of those subcollections' documents is changed, the userId wildcard is not triggered.' If so, whats the difference between your solution and that statement?

Comment: Assuming you're asking about the second snippet: a change in a `stringrays` document will indeed not trigger any functions on its parent document, but that wasn't the use-case we're discussing here as far as I can tell.